# If a published WP plugin changed name and file structure, what is the best way to upload the update into WP repository?

Tags: wordpress, svn

I have failed finding a straight answer to these questions, which has prevented me from publishing the new version of my WP plugin for some months now. I lack in deeper understanding of SVN (used by WP repository) and also I do not wish to mess something up and cause problems for people who use the plugin and decide to update it (less than thousand installations, but still, I know a lot of people depend on it for their websites to work as intended).

In the new version of the plugin, I have two major changes:

1. The plugin name has changed to reflect on new functionalities, but also I'd prefer if the name of the plugin folder changes as well.
2. I rewrote the plugin almost from scratch, which led to a completely new file/folder structure. This code is in it's own place, and not moved into the trunk yet.

Naturally I'd like the old plugin to be able to update itself into the new version, as it already has a user base. The new version is made to play nicely with old one, if uploaded manually as a zip package.

So the question is, what would be the best way to publish the new version into the Wordpress plugin repository, keeping in mind that

1. Plugin's folder name should change (if possible at all), and
2. All the old files from current latest tag should not exist in the new version, due to a complete code rewrite.

Please help, so I can finally move on with this project.

Answer (score 0):

1. As confirmed by WP support, changing the plugin folder name is impossible.
2. Not a real answer to the question, but in light of answer to 1., I'll just add a new plugin to repo, and update the old one with notifications for users who wish a more complex plugin to replace it.